# Is "type" a function or class?

Tags: python, function, class, object, types

I'm a little confused about `type` as it is listed in Built-in Functions in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type).

However, when I run `type(type)` and `type.__dict__` it looks more like a callable class. Besides that calling `isinstance(type, type)` returns `True`. What's going on?

Comment: In CPython (the reference implementation of Python you download from python.org), `type` is simply an object of instance of `PyType_Type` that is automatically populated into the builtin namespace by the interpreter. You can find its definition in the CPython source, e.g. the [bltinmodule](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ffd9753a944916ced659b2c77aebe66a6c9fbab5/Python/bltinmodule.c).

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed. It is a _very_ specific question about what `type` actually is, given that is behaves like an object, but also like a class object since it is an instance of itself.

Comment: @Brian Reactions to the initial title..

Answer (score 2):

`type` is a class, a.k.a. a type - the terms are mostly equivalent in Python 3, although the `typing` module introduced a separate, subtly incompatible usage of the word "type".

It's documented under "built-in functions" because that's the clearest place to document what it does when you call it like a function. There are a bunch of types documented there. If you look at the top of the page, you'll see

> The Python interpreter has a number of functions **and types** built into it that are always available. They are listed here in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

`type` is a type. It's the metaclass of other built-in types (including itself)

```
>>> type(int)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(type)
<class 'type'>
```

as well as the default metaclass for user-defined types:

```
>>> class A: pass
...
>>> type(A)
<class 'type'>
```

When called with one argument (as in the preceding examples), it returns the type of its argument. When called with three arguments (a name, a tuple of base classes, and a `dict`), it returns a new instance of `type`, as one might expect when calling a type.

```
>>> B = type('B', (A,), {'x': 3})
>>> type(B)
<class 'type'>
>>> B.x
3
```

In fact, a `class` statement is a declarative syntax for a call to `type`. The preceding is equivalent to

```
class B(A):
    x = 3
```